# IEEE-754 Floating Point Exponent Alignment Issue

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm making a floating point calculator from the ground up basically, and I'm having an issue with the part where you align the exponents of two numbers in the case that they are not equal.

For instance:
75.2 + 12.25 = 84.75

But my program is instead returning 106.5

Here is the code for the function that aligns the exponents:

```
void align(MyStruct* a, MyStruct* b)
{
   if (a->exponent > b->exponent)
   {
      b->exponent = a->exponent; // Sets the exponent of b = to a 
      b->fraction >>= a->exponent - b->exponent // Shifts the mantissa (fraction) bits of b to the right
   }
   return;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The binary representation for the example equation above is as shown:

`0|10000101|00100010000000000000000 A`

`0|10000010|10001000000000000000000 B +`

When I do `b->exponent = a->exponent;`, I'm expecting it to make b

`0|10000101|10001000000000000000000`, which goes smoothly. Then I expect the mantissa portion of b to be shifted right as many times is necessary to make up for the added bits that go past the 23 bit limit (in this case, it's 3) This also happens without issue, leaving b to become
`0|10000101|00010001000000000000000`

As far as this, I would expect to get the correct results. However it does not produce the correct number. Looking into it further with other floating point calculators online, it appears that the result of a + b is represented as `0|10000101|01010011000000000000000` in binary.

However, when adding my two modified mantissas together, that is not the result I get. What am I doing wrong here? The only thing I suspect is that the hidden bit (the 1) is not being shifted during the process. Is this the case?

I should mention that my structs are composed of three integer variables, each of which represent the individual parts of the IEEE-754 floating point formation (sign, exponent, fraction/mantissa). So the mantissa for A for example would be `00000000000100010000000000000000` (32 bits instead of 23, but when they're all parsed it becomes the full representation of the float). Also, I am pretty positive that my other functions are working as intended, and that the align is the issue here.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you remembering to put in the implicit 1 before the binary point? That should be done before shifting the significand.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan My understanding was that this bit was not actually there, no? It was just understood that it was there--which would be more efficient seeing as it would allow for more precision.

Comment: Well, yes, it's implicit, but it should still participate in the shift. When you shift `1.1` right by one bit, it should become `0.11` but you are turning it into `1.01`

Comment: So this bit wouldn't be included in the fraction though, I would just simulate it's existence, correct? By that I mean my variable which holds the fraction `int fraction` for example, will wouldn't be `000000001|10000000000000000000000`. But rather `000000000|10000000000000000000000`, and I would just simulate the bit past the 23rd place?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably extract the pieces out of IEEE representation into local variables with more bits to spare (materializing the implicit bit at this point), do the math, and then pack the result back into the representation (which involves normalizing it and removing the high bit, so it's implicit again). It doesn't make sense to me to try and stay within IEEE the whole time, since you need denormal numbers as intermediate results, and IEEE representation is not designed for that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah that's what I was saying. Each portion of the IEEE format is stored into its own variable. So the fraction portion, although only 23 bits when it's complete, is actually 32 bits. I can manipulate the bits past 23 if I wish because of this. I would do this just by setting the 24th bit, right?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yup that seemed to fix the issue. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Answers should be entered as answers, not edited into the question.

Comment: Re “The bit technically doesn't exist”: This is the wrong way to think about it. The bit does technically exist. There is a mathematical model of floating-point numbers (several, actually): A floating-point number represented using a sign (+1 or −1) s, a significand S, and an exponent E such that the number represented is s•S•2^E. We **encode** these things in bits. If the number is normal, then, for s, we write 0 for +1 or 1 for −1. For E, we calculate E+127 in binary and write eight bits for that. We skip the first bit of S and write the next 23 bits. That makes an encoding of the number.

Comment: The encoding is just bits representing the number. The bits in it for the exponent are not the exponent; they are an encoding that gives us a way to get the actual exponent. The bits in it for the significand are not the significand; they are part of an encoding that gives us a way to get the actual significand (write “1.” then the 23 bits from the encoding). If the number is subnormal, shift the actual significand S as needed, and it will start with “0.”. To encode it, we skip that “0.” and put the next 23 bits in the encoding. For the exponent, we put 00000000. Again, this is an encoding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm confused though, for a 32 bit number, wouldn't that be impossible? 1 + 8 + 24 exceeds the size. By "techincally doesn't exist", I was referring to the fact that it's not physically represented in a computer. Or is that wrong?

Comment: That encoding gives us a way to get the actual significand. Because the exponent is 0, we know the significand starts with “0.”. Then we append the 23 bits from the significand field. The result is the full significand, which always has that leading bit. The bits stored in the significand field are just part of an encoding; they are not the actual full significand.

Comment: @EthanR: Of course the actual significand is **represented**. You could not know what the significand was if it were not represented. We store **all** bits of the significand in some way. That way is that one bit is conveyed via the exponent field: If the exponent field is non-zero, the first bit of the significand is 1. If it is zero, the first bit of the significand is 0. The 23 bits in the primary significand field give 23 more bits. That makes 24 bits. The stored bits **always** tell you all 24 bits of the significand. Never think the 23-bit field is, by itself, the full significand.

Comment: Even though you already solved your problem, it would be nice to provide actually compiling code (i.e. a [mre]). That must include the definition of `MyStruct` as well as not writing syntactically wrong things like `b.exponent-> =  ...` (people are much more likely willing to help, if they can just copy+paste and compile your code)

Comment: Also, please remove the "FIXED" part from the question. Questions are already marked as resolved, once you accept an answer (and there is nothing wrong with accepting your own answer).

Comment: @chtz I tried to give as much clarity as possible while maintaining brevity. I’m on a bit of a time crunch, and I believed it was a simple problem that I explained pretty well. I also don’t know what you mean by syntactically wrong? Do you mean that it wouldn’t compile with that syntax? If so, you are wrong.

Comment: You most likely meant `b->exponent` and not `b.exponent->` (just copy+paste the code you were actually running into the question)

Comment: @chtz Oh wait haha. I just saw I did type it incorrectly. The reason I did not copy paste was to make it as clear and simple as I could. There was a lot of unrelated fluff and variables were named differently, so I chose to show a simpler, easy to read version. I apologize for being ignorant there.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe the calculation would have been wrong even if I did not fix the issue to begin with because I was shifting based on the difference between the exponents, however that would mean I'm shifting 0 times since I set the exponents equal to one another. So that was a silly oversight by me.
2. The actual issue was resolved by setting the 24th bit in the mantissa being shifted. The bit *technically* doesn't exist, but as someone pointed out, it is implied to be there and will be moved over when the shifting occurs.

The fixed code would be as:

```
void align(MyStruct* a, MyStruct* b)
{
    if (a->exponent != b->exponent) // If the exponents are not equal
    {
        if (a->exponent > b->exponent)
        {
            int disp = a->exponent - b->exponent; // number of shifts needed based on difference between two exponents
            a->fraction |= 1 << 23; // sets the implicit bit for shifting
            b->exponent = a->exponent; // sets exponents equal to each other
            a->fraction >>= disp; // mantissa is shifted over to accommodate for the increase in power
            return;
        }
        int disp = b->exponent - a->exponent;
        a->fraction |= 1 << 23;
        a->exponent = b->exponent;
        a->fraction >>= disp;
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks to those that helped!

Comment: The bit exists in every sense except for being physically stored. It does not need to be stored because its value can be deduced from the exponent. For all zero exponent numbers it is zero. For all other numbers, owing to normalization, it is one.

Comment: I am not sure this code is correct, but cannot be sure it is wrong without seeing the definitions. I recommend testing it with two numbers that have different exponents and non-zero low significance bits.